# Microsoft Graph - Difference between calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have tried to go through the documentation but didnt get a clear idea about difference in below calls:

```
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/{calendarId}/events
```

I did query them separately and they are returning same number of results. Which one is most efficient to use and in what scenarios each one of them is used.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a list of events in **a user's all calendars** you can use

```
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

To retrieve a list of events in **a user's default calendar** you can use

```
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events
```

To retrieve a list of events in **a user's specific calendar in the default calendarGroup**.

```
GET users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/{calendarId}/events
```

First endpoint will return more results than second and third endpoint.

If all endpoints return the same number of results then it means that you have only one calendar.

Comment: thanks! I believe in first endpoint you mean a user's all calendars, right?